# how to send remote script parameters through expect script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, expect

I have a program that creates a dynamic shell script using heredoc "stop_remoteServer_script.sh"

template of heredoc below

```
cat<<_STOP > stop_remoteServer_script.sh
#!/bin/bash

serverName=\$1
function getServerpid {
        pid=\$( ps -ef|grep \${serverName}|grep -v grep |awk '{print \$2}' )
        echo \$pid
}

function kill_soaServer {
        echo "Killing \${serverName} ........"
        ps -ef|grep \${serverName} |grep -v grep|awk '{print \$2}'|xargs kill -9
        echo "status of killing server is $?"
}

check_soaServer=\$( getServerpid );

while [[ "X\${check_soaServer}" != "X" ]]
do
        cmd_status=\$( kill_soaServer  )
        sleep 30s
        check_soaServer=\$( getServerpid  )
done

kill_soaServer \${serverName}
_STOP
```

actual script that goes to remote box for execution

template output

```
#!/bin/bash

serverName=$1
function getServerpid {
        pid=$( ps -ef|grep ${serverName}|grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}' )
        echo $pid
}

function kill_soaServer {
        echo "Killing ${serverName} ........"
        ps -ef|grep ${serverName} |grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
        echo "status of killing server is 0"
}

check_soaServer=$( getServerpid );

while [[ "X${check_soaServer}" != "X" ]]
do
        cmd_status=$( kill_soaServer  )
        sleep 30s
        check_soaServer=$( getServerpid  )
done

kill_soaServer ${serverName}
```

Now I have a below expect block of code which will invoke the above generated code in remote box with a parameter of server name

```
sName=$1

CMD="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  ${remoteUserName}\@${remoteHostName} "

# script with parameter
script="./stop_remoteServer_script.sh ${sName}"

/usr/bin/expect<<END
set force_conservative 0
spawn bash  -c "${CMD} /bin/bash < ${script} "
expect  "* password: "
send -- "${MYPWD}\r"
expect  "*$*"
expect eof

END
```

The error I am getting is below

```
spawn bash -c ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  sgngli@den00qoc.us.sdc.com  /bin/bash < ./stop_remoteServer_script.sh soa_server2
sgngli@den00qoc.us.sdc.com's password:
/bin/bash: soa_server2: No such file or directory
```

can any one help me how to send the parameter , manually it works

===================

additional try based on the suggetions :

I have created a simple network using virtual box and tried below

main program

```
#!/bin/bash
# script with parameter
echo "running exp example"
sName="abc123ibc"
script="a.sh"
echo "thes script is $script \n"
/usr/bin/expect -d <<END
set force_conservative 0
set timeout -1
set prompt "*$*"
puts "before swapn"
spawn scp ./a.sh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ansibleadm\@192.168.1.102:/home/ansibleadm/
expect "id_rsa*"
send -- "ansibleadm\r"
expect  "*$*"
expect eof
puts "second spawn"
spawn ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ansibleadm\@192.168.1.102  /bin/bash -c  ./a.sh $sName > log.txt
expect "id_rsa*"
send -- "ansibleadm\r"
expect ""
puts "after spawn"
expect eof
END
```

there is another a.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
  
sleep 12s
echo "inside swapned script"
touch ~/sample.txt
cat > ~/sample.txt<<EOF
hi suman $1
EOF
```

in the sample.txt what i am always getting is below the variable is missing

```
[ansibleadm@AppServer ~]$ cat sample.txt 
hi suman
```

I have enabled the debugger of the expect and below are debug log

```
[ansibleadm@Centos-Control ~]$ ./exp.sh 
running exp example
thes script is a.sh \n
expect version 5.45.4
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  
set argc 0
set argv0 "/usr/bin/expect"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file
before swapn
spawn scp ./a.sh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ansibleadm@192.168.1.102:/home/ansibleadm/
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {33533}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "id_rsa*"? no
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ansibleadm/.ssh/id_rsa': 
expect: does "\rEnter passphrase for key '/home/ansibleadm/.ssh/id_rsa': " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "id_rsa*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "id_rsa': "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\rEnter passphrase for key '/home/ansibleadm/.ssh/id_rsa': "
send: sending "ansibleadm\r" to { exp6 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ""
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""

a.sh                                                                                        100%  114   165.9KB/s   00:00    
-o: No such file or directory
StrictHostKeyChecking=no: No such file or directory
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n\ra.sh                                                                                          
 ||| 0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\ra.sh                                                                                        
 ||| 100%  114   165.9KB/s   00:00    \r\n-o: No such file or directory\r\nStrictHostKeyChecking=no: No such file or directory\r\n"
second spawn
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ansibleadm@192.168.1.102 /bin/bash -c ./a.sh abc123ibc > log.txt
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {33541}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp10) match glob pattern "id_rsa*"? no
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ansibleadm/.ssh/id_rsa': 
expect: does "\rEnter passphrase for key '/home/ansibleadm/.ssh/id_rsa': " (spawn_id exp10) match glob pattern "id_rsa*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "id_rsa': "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp10"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\rEnter passphrase for key '/home/ansibleadm/.ssh/id_rsa': "
send: sending "ansibleadm\r" to { exp10 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp10) match glob pattern ""? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ""
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp10"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
after spawn

expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp10"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n"
[ansibleadm@Centos-Control ~]$
```

Comment: You didn't need to show **any** of the generation of the script: it has no bearing whatsoever on the error message.

Comment: Question: does the generated script reside on the remote host or only locally?

Comment: Note, in the `kill_soaServer` function, you forgot to escape `$?`

Comment: answer for the question : it stays in local folder and i am referring that script  in expect block spawn .. I do read ,there is parsing happen  bash > expect   bash parses first and then expect parses next hence \\ escape is required

Comment: When using `bash -c command a b c` the args `a b c` will set `$0 $1 $2`, so to pass arg XXX as `$1` you need to say `bash -c command dummy XXX`. This is not the case for `-s` when you just say `bash -s <somefile XXX`.

Comment: I figured it out the  solution is  bash -c ' /path/to/script arg1 arg2 arg3'  now script would take the arg1 and arg2 inside

Answer (score 1):

To ask `bash` to read commands from stdin you need the `-s` option, followed by the arguments to pass to the invocation. Eg:

```bsh
$ echo 'date +$1' | bash -s %Y
2021
```

so add `-s` after `/bin/bash`  in your `spawn` command.

---

Note, for `-c` the arguments after the command set `$0` first so you need to do, for example:

```
bash -c 'echo $(date +$1)' dummy %Y
```

Comment: I have tried that one , the problem is  here ,bash is at outer layer which accepts a script file and that script needs a parameters  , and that to i have to send in this format /bin/bash < ./stop_remoteServer_script.sh soa_server2 , where soa_server2 is input to the  .sh file and .sh file is input to bash

Comment: If i try your way , it did nothing .

Comment: Are you adding the `-s` to the second bash command? `spawn bash  -c "${CMD} /bin/bash -s < ${script} "`

Comment: HI , spawn bash  -c "${CMD} /bin/bash -s < ${script} " there is parameter also required to pass  -c "${CMD} /bin/bash -s < ${script}  ${param}"   the param is for script and not for bash

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating the spawn:

```
CMD="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  ${remoteUserName}\@${remoteHostName} "

# script with parameter
script="./stop_remoteServer_script.sh ${sName}"

/usr/bin/expect<<END
  set force_conservative 0
  spawn ${CMD} bash ${script}
  ...
```

And if the script has execute permissions, you can drop `bash` too.

---

Because the $script variable contains whitespace:

1. this: `/bin/bash < ${script}`
2. turns into this: `/bin/bash < ./stop_remoteServer_script.sh soa_server2`
3. which bash interprets as: `/bin/bash soa_server2 < ./stop_remoteServer_script.sh`
4. resulting in the "soa_server2: No such file" error

Comment: what if i use script="./stop_remoteServer_script.sh\ ${sName}". adding extra escape for space , then it would go  bash > expect > bash without harming space

Comment: Ye You are correct ,, that is how expect parses first and then give it bash and again bash parses

Comment: Hi Glenn, I have updated the question with a new simpler program with expect debugger on still i am unable to receive the parameter

Comment: I figured it out  the solution is  bash -c '/path/to/script. arg1 arg2 '  arg1 and arg2 would go in to script rather bash command